# Get the output of print (without carriage return) in python

Tags: python, printing

Given a string containing '\n' and '\r', I want to be able to get the output remaining string that would be displayed by the print function.
(That is, \n would make a new line and \r would make overwriting)

```py
from io import StringIO

output = StringIO()
output.write('Start\n')
output.write('First line\r')
output.write('Second line')

str(output.getvalue())
```

This outputs: 'Start\nFirst line\rSecond line'.

I want to get: 'Start\nSecond line'

Is there an easy way to do so, or should I loop through the string and manually change it ?

Comment: On Linux you could use the `subprocess` module to execute the `col` utility, which emulates a terminal to figure out the resulting output of a string with control sequences like this.

Comment: Interesting... I tried `os.popen('echo "Line1\rLine2" | col').read()`, but I get some weird `'L\x08Li\x08in\x08ne\x08e1\x082\n'`

Comment: Ok, and then a regex like `re.sub(".\x08", "", subprocess_output_str)` can do the trick. That would work - thanks for the tip !
But if any more pythonic way is available, I would still be interested !

Comment: Pipe to `col -b`, not just `col`.